# How should we handle .csproj and web.config with visualsvn

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

Context : Windows 7, VS 2010, Tortoise SVN , and VisualSVN (all up to date)

We have some problems with our web.config files and .csproj : in these files there is informations common to the whole project (like connection string, configuration element) and informations depending on the machine (mostly file path).

So the problem is, each time I commit my web.config, my colleague has to go back to his file and change the file paths.

Did you find any way to handle it ? I tried to remove these from source control but it's kind of a problem  (each time someone add a file to the project we have to add it manually, or a configuration key).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way we've handled file paths in the web.config is through the use of symbolic links.
i.e. in the commited web.config have the files paths point to e.g. `C:\website` then on each developers machine run the following command:

```
mklink /d C:\Website c:\path\to\develper\specific\checkout
```

Thus no-one should need to re-edit the paths to point to their workspace.

We've not had problems with our .csproj files - they don't have machine specific config in them.

We did however have similar issues with app.config settings.  Again solved by either having each developer store files in a set location or having a symbolic link from the set location to their location.

For connection strings, we've either got them all set to `localhost` or set them to `localdatabase` and have a host entry on each developers machine.  This will only work if each developer connects to the same database name but on a different server.  If you're connecting to the same database server but different databases, you'll need a different tactic.

Comment: Good idea I'll try it. We don't have problem with database, we use the same local database (in another computer on the local network). So in fact the only problem was the file path.Thank you